# Alfresco how to send email to other domain

Tags: alfresco

I have configured the alfresco email outbound like this

```
 mail.host=mailserver.com
 mail.port=25
 mail.username=uname
 mail.password=pword
```

now I can send mail to email address like `abc@mailserver.com` but `abc@otherdomain.com`.
how to send email to other domai? thanks!!!(my alfresco edition is community 4.2.x)

Comment: Are you sure it's an Alfresco problem? Most likely you've just neglected to configure your mail server to allow relaying....

Comment: Should be.Beacause I use same mailserver to send email in custom java method, it totally ok. so I ask a question here.

Comment: What error do you see on the Alfresco side? And what errors / warnings / messages show up in the mail server logs when you try to send?

Comment: Unable to relay for abc@otherdomain.com
; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay for abc@otherdomain.com

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1047)
... 100 more

Comment: ok,may be it's my problem, This problem may be within the intranet causes, I will connect company engineer to solve it.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer...

Alfresco itself has absolutely no problems with sending emails to any destination domain

However, when you setup outbound SMTP for Alfresco, you specify a mail server to use for handling outbound messages. *That* server needs to be configured to allow mail relaying from the Alfresco host. If it isn't, then you'll often see that internal emails are fine, but external emails are rejected. Make sure your mail server is configured to allow Alfresco to send (relay) emails through it, and you'll be fine!

Answer (score 0):

To send an email to alfresco using the rule “Send an email to a specified user“ you must modify first the file alfresco-global.properties. This file is located in the folder “tomcatsharedclasses“.

```
mail.host=your host
mail.port=25
mail.username=your mail user
mail.password=your mail password
mail.encoding=UTF-8
mail.from.default=optional name
mail.smtp.auth=true
```

Finally, you can change the template of email notification in the file **notify_user_email.ftl** in Company Home/Data Dictionary/Email Templates/Notify Email Templates.

For complete example see here:
https://lentux-informatica.com/how-to-send-email-through-alfresco/